# Windows batch for loop with find command does not work in a folder with a lot of files

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, find

I need to count the number of occurrences of a particular string in each file in a folder.
Each line of a file can have only zero or one occurrence of this string.

```
for %%g in (*) do Find /c "Order" "%%g" >> Orders.txt
```

The above batch runs OK in a folder with e.g. 9 files and produces the following output:

```
---------- ABCD_GHKL345678_20220204190418.JSON: 256

---------- ABCD_EFGH456789_20220217150329.JSON: 3
```

Then I import this file into EXCEL and complete processing.

However when I execute the same batch file in a folder with about 6000 files, it outputs the same "1" value for each file like:

```
---------- ABCD_GHKL345678_20220204190418.JSON: 1

---------- ABCD_EFGH456789_20220217150329.JSON: 1
```

What's wrong with this batch?

Why does it run OK in a folder with several files and fails in a folder with a lot of files?

Is there a limit for the number of files that FOR loop can process?

Comment: Why do you use double variable name **for %%gg** ? Perhaps your problem were caused by binary files in folder (with over 6000files).

Comment: Warming to the theme, apart from the incorrect `gg` as noted, try `*.json` to select just the `.json` files - and could it be that those files are all actually 1 line (ie.contain no newlines?)

Comment: @Daemon-5, you are right. 
I reformatted files in my test folder with JSON beautifier and forgot about it.

Comment: How can I accept an answer? I do not see any checkmark to toggle.

Comment: You have not received any answers - only comments. Seems the problem was finger trouble...

Answer (score 0):

Each file had only single line.
My assumption that each occurrence of this string was on a separate line was wrong.
So my `Find /c "Order"` command worked as designed but not how I expected.

Thank you @Daemon-5 for telling me to check this.